# LZW compression method not compressing TIFF image with imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I have following code to manipulate and compress the TIFF image.

```
<?php

try{
    $imagesrc = "C:\\server\\www\\imagick\\src.tif";
    $imagedestination = "C:\\server\\www\\imagick\\converted.tif";
    $im=new Imagick();
    $im->readImage($imagesrc); //read image for manipulation
    $im->setImageColorSpace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);

    $im->setImageDepth(8); //8 Bit

    $im->setImageResolution(300,300); //set output resolution to 300 dpi
    $im->setImageUnits(1); //0=undefined, 1=pixelsperInch, 2=PixelsPerCentimeter
    $im->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW);
    $im->setImageCompressionQuality(80);
    $im->writeImage($imagedestination);
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();
    $im=NULL;
}catch(ImagickException $e){
     echo "Could not convert image  - ".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The source image is 19MB. When I use this code, the resulting TIF image is around 25MB. That is, the code is not compressing image at all.  Also other compression methods have no effect on resulting TIFF file but however if i use compression method `Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG`, the resulting image is 2MB

I can't use JPEG compression, as I m using resulting TIFF image with `itextsharp` to embed in PDF. JPEG compression results in multi-strip tiff image which is not supported by itextsharp.

So there are two possible answers to my question. And either of the answer will work for me

1. How to effectively compress the tif?
2. How to convert multi-strip tif image into single strip.

Thanks

Comment: `The source image is 19MB` - that sounds like a rather large image, given that COMPRESSION_LZW/q=0.8 generates an even bigger filer. The dimensions of the image are a given and can't be changed?

Comment: What are the dimensions of your image?

Comment: @VolkerK, We can compromise in a quality but not in image dimension. The image dimension is 3655x3735 pixels. The source image dimension and size may vary depending upon what user uploads.

Comment: Sorry for nagging: `in a quality but not in image dimension` the tiff format can store the dpi - is it really the pixel size you need to be constant or the output dimensions (as pixel/dpi)? I see you set the dpi to 300, but would it be aceptable to have it at 72 as well?

Comment: @VolkerK, pixel size need to be constant. That means, we can change DPI, but i tried with that too, i changed output DPI from 300 to 170, no change in file size.

Comment: Oh, it just occurred to me that our goal is to embed this image in a pdf document via itextsharp. a) So the output doesn't necessarily have to be a tiff but could be a jpeg as well. That's what you meant when you wrote about trying `Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG` - I don't think you can do that when the output format is tiff. b) you're already using .net in the project - would a .net solution for converting the image be ok?

Comment: @VolkerK, I m working on old project, so I m not in position to make any drastic changes to the project. So far the image is concerned, it doesn't matter what method you use to compress the image, the final PDF is meant for printing in the press, so the image mime type must be tiff and must be of CMYK colorspace

Comment: Still in question mode ;-) The php script serves a purpose; what was/is the problem it _must_ solve? a) Is the input file too big? b) Is it to make sure the image is a tiff/CMYK? c) Make sure it's 8bit? d) Has specific dimensions? e) Has a specific dpi? So which of these properties does the input file _not_ have? | On your initial question: apparantley if the imagemagick core hasn't been compiled with lzw support COMPRESSION_LZW will be silently dropped which results in an uncompressed image :-S

Comment: @VolkerK, the big image file result in big PDF file, so I want to compress the tiff image. The only thing that needs to be unchanged is pixel dimension of the image, rest of thing thing are compromisable. I also checked resulted image with `identify` command and it sayz the compression method used is LZW

Answer (score 1):

Fiddling with php-imagick got me nowhere, so I tried [Magick.NET](https://magick.codeplex.com/).
Only by setting the `rows-per-strip` define a number larger than the lines in the image (i.e. #strips=1) iTextSharp accepted the image with CompressionMethod.JPEG.
But it's still not working. All the image viewers I have on my computer render the image correctly, yet in the PDF documents it's broken.
And I found this forum entry http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/TIFF-with-color-pages-COMPRESS-JPEG-problem-td3686051.html :

> Jpeg compressed tiff images are not really supported in iText, they may work but most probably not.

No idea how authoritative Paulo Soares-3's post is, but I give up.
Therefore: this is not an answer. But maybe you want to fiddle with the .NET port as well, so here's my test code - good luck :

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace imagick_itext_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static Image getNormalizedImage(string path)
        {
            Image rv;
            using (MemoryStream mems = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (ImageMagick.MagickImage image = new ImageMagick.MagickImage(path))
                {
                    image.Format = ImageMagick.MagickFormat.Tiff;
                    image.ResolutionUnits = ImageMagick.Resolution.PixelsPerInch;
                    image.Depth = 300;
                    image.BitDepth(8); // for printing you said? ;-)
                    image.Adjoin = false; // is there multi-image in jpeg anyway?
                    image.Interlace = ImageMagick.Interlace.Jpeg; // try Interlace.Plane and Interlace.No
                    image.CompressionMethod = ImageMagick.CompressionMethod.JPEG; // everything's fine when using .LZW here
                    image.Quality = 35;  // 85, 80 not even 50 got me significant reduction in file size (src size=18MB)
                    //image.SetDefine(ImageMagick.MagickFormat.Tiff, "rows-per-strip", image.Height.ToString());
                    image.SetDefine(ImageMagick.MagickFormat.Tiff, "rows-per-strip", "8192");
                    image.Strip(); // remove additional data, e.g. comments
                    image.Write(mems);
                }

                // store the tiff(jpeg) image for inspection
                using (FileStream fos = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\so_conv.tiff", FileMode.Create) )
                {
                    mems.Position = 0;
                    mems.CopyTo(fos);
                }
                mems.Position = 0;
                rv = Image.GetInstance(mems);
                //rv.ScalePercent(24f); // works for me ...
            }
            return rv;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Document doc = new Document())
            {
                using (PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"c:\temp\so_pdf_test.pdf", FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    doc.Open();
                    doc.SetMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);
                    doc.Add(new Paragraph("SO Image Test"));
                    doc.Add(getNormalizedImage(@"c:\temp\src.tif"));
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VS2012 - .net 4.5 , ImageMagick-6.8.8-10-Q16-x64-static.exe
Both Magick.NET and iTextSharp have been added via NuGet to the project:

- iTextSharp 5.50
- Magick.NET-Q16-x64 6.8.8.901

Answer (score 0):

From what i have testes its better to leave out JPEG in TIFF = is the smallest.
Then there is ZIP compression and then LZW and then RLE.

**Input file: jpeg 500kb.
 * jpeg in tiff 1.25mb
 * ZIP 2.0mb
 * LZW 2.5mb
 * LRE 3.2mb

One thing - dont set Quality for tiff compression as it is loseless format - it just ignores it (sets to 100 for counting). You may set it for the jpeg compression for tiff - nothing other.

**But what you could do is add the line `$im->stripImage();` before saving. This will strip some information from the file - maybe it will make it smaller for you.**

Also please check your Imagick version my is: ImageMagick 6.7.7-7 2012-06-21 Q16 and it works well.